# Unable to start elasticsearch on centos 7 server

Tags: elasticsearch

After installation, we got following error when started the service:

```
[2020-11-04T07:20:12,233][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives ] [test] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/elasticsearch-16982199008150233397/jna17827281711253842809.tmp: /tmp/elasticsearch-16982199008150233397/jna17827281711253842809.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

Applied the following fix:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
ES_TMPDIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp

vim /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}
-Djna.tmpdir=/var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp

ll /var/lib/elasticsearch 
total 8 
drwxr-sr-x. 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Nov  4 07:20 nodes 
drwxr-sr-x. 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Nov  4 08:10 tmp
```

Then got the following error on elasticsearch service start:

```
Nov 4 08:10:17 test systemd: Starting Elasticsearch...
Nov 4 08:10:17 test systemd-entrypoint: future versions of Elasticsearch will require Java 11; your Java version from [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre] does not meet this requirement
Nov 4 08:10:17 test systemd-entrypoint: future versions of Elasticsearch will require Java 11; your Java version from [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre] does not meet this requirement
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: #
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: #
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6768e34c95, pid=194820, tid=0x00007f67d144b700
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: #
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_262-b10) (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.262-b10 mixed mode, sharing linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # Problematic frame:
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # C [jna3377815825213492039.tmp+0x12c95] ffi_prep_closure_loc+0x15
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: #
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: #
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # An error report file with more information is saved as:
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # /var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid194820.log
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: #
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: #
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: 2020-11-04 13:10:19,805768 UTC [195028] ERROR CLogger.cc@310 Cannot log to named pipe /var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp/controller_log_194820 as it could not be opened for writing
Nov 4 08:10:19 test systemd-entrypoint: 2020-11-04 13:10:19,805841 UTC [195028] INFO Main.cc@103 Parent process died - ML controller exiting
```

Environment Details:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64

CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
elasticsearch-7.9.0-1.x86_64
```

elasticsearch.yml:

```
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
discovery.seed_hosts: ["IP ADDRESS HERE"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["${HOSTNAME}"]
bootstrap.system_call_filter: false
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a permission issue as shown in the error message, doing a fresh installation with a normal user instead of `elastic` user works fine.

Comment: ll /var/lib/elasticsearch
total 8
drwxr-sr-x. 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Nov  4 07:20 nodes
drwxr-sr-x. 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Nov  4 08:10 tmp

Comment: @ValsarajViswanathan, why this tmp foler is created inside var/lib/elasticsearch and can you paste the content of log controller_log_194820 ??

Comment: due to the first error "UnsatisfiedLinkError" we changed log path to this for testing and set permission. But due to some reason this file is not created and jvm crash reported before that. UnsatisfiedLinkError not showing after changing tmp path but the second error reported is coming now.

Comment: @ValsarajViswanathan can you tell what exactly you changed in the path and which config you changed in elasticsearch.yml for this??

Comment: vim /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
ES_TMPDIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp

vim /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}
-Djna.tmpdir=/var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp

Comment: @ValsarajViswanathan what is the content of your elasticsearch.yml, this doesn't look the content of elasticsearch config file

Comment: Above content was added as per fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681410/unable-to-start-elasticsearch-on-centos-7-server. I will add content of yml file in description as well. 
                     elasticsearch.yml:

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
discovery.seed_hosts: ["IP ADDRESS HERE"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["${HOSTNAME}"]
bootstrap.system_call_filter: false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224132/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-valsaraj-viswanathan).